# Flutter firebase notification click to open a screen

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have a flutter app where in the user has a list of tasks to be done , when clicked on the task it carries to a detail screen giving the details regarding the clicked task
I have a constructor for detailscreen

```
class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  DocumentSnapshot detailDocument;
  DetailPage(this.detailDocument);
```

it works fine
when a user gets a new task he gets a notification
my function payload is as follows

```
const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'New Task!',
        body: `${Taskdata.Title} is given by ${Taskdata.Taskgivenby}`,
        icon: 'your-icon-url',
        click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
      }
    };
    await fcm.sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        return null;
  });
```

main.dart file

```
_fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");

      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
  }
```

the problem i have is when a user clicks on the notification he should be directed to the detail page.
how could i achieve it

Comment: Are u familiar with Navigator class? And have you achieved already printing 'onResume with your message?

Comment: my onResume is not working , i am familiar with Navigator

Comment: if onResume is not working, that means you haven't configured you messages well with Flutter. Try to follow all the steps in doc: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/

Comment: I have tried using navigator to redirect to detail screen , but its still going to homecreen Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    DetailPage(message['data'])));

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of navigating without the context and I implemented something similar using the directions outlayed in this video tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=kopdISefbJc

Hope you find this helpful.